# Delete duplicate rows between two Excel sheets except Row A

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that will delete duplicate rows between two Excel sheets.

How do I set the range of my macro to remove the duplicates in rows below A, or not delete Row A?

```vb
Public Sub RemoveDuplicateRows()
    Dim ur1 As Range, ur2 As Range, dupeRows As Range
    Dim r1 As Range, s1 As String, r2 As Range, s2 As String

    Set ur1 = Worksheets("AM DATA").UsedRange.Rows
    Set ur2 = Worksheets("PM DATA").UsedRange.Rows  'Find duplicates from AM data in PM DATA

    Set dupeRows = ur2(Worksheets("PM DATA").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    For Each r1 In ur1
        s1 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r1)))
        For Each r2 In ur2
            s2 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r2)))
            If s1 = s2 Then
                If Intersect(dupeRows, r2) Is Nothing Then
                    Set dupeRows = Union(dupeRows, r2)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Delete duplicate rows in PM DATA
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    dupeRows.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Exclude Headers (First Row)

- If you want to exclude more rows, replace both ones with the appropriate number.

```vb
Sub ExcludeHeaders()
    
    Dim ur1 As Range, ur2 As Range
    
    With Worksheets("AM DATA").UsedRange
        Set ur1 = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("PM DATA").UsedRange
        Set ur2 = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With

End Sub
```